# Google map API V3, maps disappear randomly

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, google-maps-api-3

I am coming across a very weird problem using google maps. The maps are working fine but just they just disappear randomly and then after sometime they get fixed by themselves. I am using a [php wrapper class](http://code.google.com/p/php-google-map-api/) that generates google map V3 javascript code. I have also gone through the whole php wrapper class project website and there is no such issue reported.I am using it in a wordpress based website.

Moreover, I am displaying multiple maps on some pages and single map on others. But when the maps disappear, all of them just disappear only the maps controls remain there. I have checked the code over and again and I see no problem in it. I have no clue why this is happening. Here are the links of the websites

- http://knuj.ingstadbroadcasting.com/
- http://kmrskkok.ingstadbroadcasting.com/
- http://mybasin.ingstadbroadcasting.com/

Please let me know if more details are required.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The first and third pages don't even load, and the second page does not appear to have a map.

Comment: @Matt Ball: The sites might be down because of some server updates. I have taken a snapshot of the second site and put it in my question so that you can see the area where maps are displayed. Also if in case maps disappear you know its location.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem in one project: I had a hidden div containing a Gmap, when I make mouse over to image, this map show correctly.

But, if I make this action any times and drag the map, the background (the map background images, the road, ground, etc..) doesn't show.

The problem its caused, because the Gmap tries to rewrite when its hidden, and in this state the map doesn't have width & height (you can´t get this values if a div is hidden).

The only solution I find, is to not make the map hidden. Use opacity, z-index or move the map outside of the window (top -99999, left -99999).

PD: and yes.. its a fuc*** bug...

Comment: Thanks for your input. I faced this problem but I resolved it and now the problem is a little different, divs are not hidden. The map body appears with controls in it but there is no content at all. I have put the snapshot of the problem in the question please take a look. I have edited it once again.